# Could we remove the resistor in parallel with voltage source or in series with current source?

Tags: power, resistance, source

Although this question have been asked. But I want to ask again. I still doubt about it. It is written in "Electric Circuits (9th Edition) by  James W. Nilsson, Susan Riedel". And if we remove it, I think it'd change the power in circuit. I'm confused now.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The text has the answer: *The circuits are equivalent with respect to terminals a,b*. Of course the power will change, but that is not relevant for the rest of the circuit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the way I teach it:

Adding or removing a resistor in parallel with an ideal voltage source changes only the current through (and thus the power associated with) the voltage source - no other circuit variable is changed.

Adding or removing a resistor in series with an ideal current source changes only the voltage across (and thus the power associated with) the current source - no other circuit variable is changed.

Thus, to solve for the other circuit variables, one may remove any resistor in parallel with a voltage source and short any resistor in series with a current source without affecting the circuit solution (*except* as mentioned above).

---

As an aside, do note that Thevenin and Norton equivalent circuits are equivalent only from the perspective of what an attached circuit 'sees'.

That is to say, if one had two black boxes with two exposed terminals each, one a Thevenin equivalent and the other the dual Norton equivalent, the terminal voltage and current would be identical for a given attached circuit.

*However*, one could easily tell the two apart with a thermometer.  Do you see why this is so?

Answer (score 1):

As @venny mentioned, and the text they are the same with respect to the terminals a and b

For any Rl that you attach to node A and node B, you will get the same voltage or current because these are ideal voltage and current sources.

If we look at 4.39a, they are the same because the voltage on Rp will **always** be equal to Vs. So if we we remove resistor Rp, it has no effect because the voltage at that node will always be equal to Vs. Make sense ?

The same is true for the current source, beacuse the current source will **always** provide that current.